# What is wrong in this sorting array skipping some elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have array of objects. I want sort it leave some elements in the same position (with b="NOT")

```js
var a=[{a:1,b:"YES"},{a:2,b:"YES"},{a:5,b:"NOT"},{a:0,b:"NOT"},{a:0,b:"YES"}]

function sortc(x,y){

  if (x.b=="NOT" || y.b=="NOT")
    return Infinity ;
     
  return (Number(x.a)-Number(y.a))
                 
}

console.log(a.sort(sortc));
```

the result is :

```
0: {a: 1, b: "YES"}
1: {a: 2, b: "YES"}
2: {a: 5, b: "NOT"}
3: {a: 0, b: "NOT"}
4: {a: 0, b: "YES"}
```

The expected result was ( with sort components with b="YES".) :

```
{ "a": 0, "b": "YES" }
{ "a": 1, "b": "YES" }
{ "a": 5, "b": "NOT" }
{ "a": 0, "b": "NOT" }
{ "a": 2, "b": "YES" }
```

Comment: "*I want sort it leave some elements in the same position (with b="NOT")*" returning `Infinite` is not actually leaving them at the same place. Just means that `y` should be sorted after `x`.

Comment: You should be using actual `boolean` values (`true`/`false`) instead of `string` values to represent boolean values.

Comment: `Number(x.a)` is unnecessary as `x.a` is already a `number` value.

Comment: Can you include the desired output?

Comment: @VLAZ The "the result is" section appears to be the incorrect result, not the desired one.

Comment: @Aplet123 you're right...

Comment: Hmm, I answered before I notices this was closed. I guess it was clear to me but I do agree that the desired output should be included. I assume you expect `{ "a": 0, "b":  "YES" }, { "a": 1, "b": "YES" },  { "a": 5, "b": "NOT" }, { "a": 0, "b": "NOT" }, { "a": 2, "b": "YES" }` but I might be wrong. Can you please clarify? I'd gladly vote to reopen when that happens. If needed, I'd amend my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot only sort *some* items using the [`Array#sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) method - you either sort all or none. You don't define the position of the items, either - you only have to define their relationship to other items and the sorting algorithm will take care of the rest.

What you can do as a workaround is

1. Extract all items that *should* be sorted.
2. Sort them.
3. Go over the original array and only replace anything that should be sorted, leave the rest of the items in their place.

```js
var a = [
  { a: 1, b: "YES" }, 
  { a: 2, b: "YES" },
  { a: 5, b: "NOT" }, 
  { a: 0, b: "NOT" }, 
  { a: 0, b: "YES" }
]

//get only `b: "YES"` items
const dataToSort = a.filter(item => item.b === "YES");

//sort them
dataToSort.sort((x, y) => x.a - y.a);

//replace only items that need to be sorted
const it = dataToSort.values()
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].b === "NOT")
    continue;
    
  a[i] = it.next().value;
}

console.log(a);
```

For the record, the final loop can just be replaced with even shorter with more iterator usage, although it might be slightly more confusing:

```
const it = dataToSort.values()
for (const [key, item] of a.entries()) { //use the key-value iterator from the array
  if (item.b === "NOT")
    continue;
    
  [a[key]] = it; //array destructuring internally advances an iterator
}
```

```js
var a = [
  { a: 1, b: "YES" }, 
  { a: 2, b: "YES" },
  { a: 5, b: "NOT" }, 
  { a: 0, b: "NOT" }, 
  { a: 0, b: "YES" }
]

//get only `b: "YES"` items
const dataToSort = a.filter(item => item.b === "YES");

//sort them
dataToSort.sort((x, y) => x.a - y.a);

//replace only items that need to be sorted
const it = dataToSort.values()
for (const [key, item] of a.entries()) {
  if (item.b === "NOT")
    continue;
    
  [a[key]] = it;
}

console.log(a);
```

---

Finally, this can be made somewhat more convenient with helper [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and few small utility functions

```js
/*  library code  */

const transformArg = transform => f => (...args) => f(transform(...args));

function* filter(predicate, it) {
  for (const item of it) {
    if (predicate(item))
      yield item;
  }
}

/*  /library code  */

var a = [
  { a: 1, b: "YES" }, 
  { a: 2, b: "YES" },
  { a: 5, b: "NOT" }, 
  { a: 0, b: "NOT" }, 
  { a: 0, b: "YES" }
]

/* helpers */
//extract the `b` key in this case so we don't need to repeat it. 
const getSortableAttribute = transformArg(({b}) => b);
//get the value from key-value pair
const getValue = transformArg(([, value]) => value);
//check if the attribute is "YES"
const isSortable = getSortableAttribute(attr => attr === "YES");

const dataToSort = a.filter(isSortable);

dataToSort.sort((x, y) => x.a - y.a);

const it = dataToSort.values()
//iterate only over sortable key-value pairs by re-using the `isSortable` filter
for (const [key, item] of filter(getValue(isSortable), a.entries())) {
  [a[key]] = it;
}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Nice use of `.values()` iterator. You can also use `a[i] = dataToSort.shift()` if it's too confusing for OP

Comment: I'm not a fan of it, as it modifies the array and then moves all the indexes down. For sufficiently large arrays it could be a performance problem. Although `.reverse()` + `.pop()` partially helps.

Comment: reverse + pop is faster than shift?

Comment: Or `sort` in descending order and then `pop` :)

Comment: I don't worry about the mutation but the change of all the indexes. Each `.shift()` is `O(n)` as it has to move all the items down an index in the array. Unless there is opimisations I'm not aware of, that's what I expect would happen. So, three `.shift()` operations on an array with 10 items will have to move 9, then 8, then 7 items down a slot. Reverse is a single `O(n)` and `.pop()` is then `O(1)`, so it's overall better.

Comment: Yeah, I guess sort descending also works now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach by using `sort` directly, but shaping the access with a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for `length` and the indices.

```js
const
    sortOnly = (array, indices) => new Proxy(array, {
        get (target, prop) {
            if (isFinite(prop)) return target[indices[prop]];
            if (prop === 'length') return indices.length;
            return target[prop];
        },
        set (target, prop, receiver) {
            target[indices[prop]] = receiver;
            return true;
        }
    }),
    array = [{ a: 1, b: "YES" }, { a: 2, b: "YES" }, { a: 5, b: "NOT" }, { a: 0, b: "NOT" }, { a: 0, b: "YES" }];

sortOnly(array, [...array.keys()].filter(i => array[i].b !== 'NOT'))
    .sort((a, b) => a.a - b.a)

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```